# Do pure functions have only one possible implementation?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

In the image below there is a quick explanation, why pure functions appear to have only one possible implementation.
I don't really get the idea because `(++) : ('a -> 'b) -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b` for example can clearly be implemented by `let (++) (f: ('a -> 'b)) (g: ('a -> 'b)) x = f x` or
`let (++) (f: ('a -> 'b)) (g: ('a -> 'b)) x = g x`

Is that image just wrong or do I miss something here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is wrong if you consider the counterexample you just gave. I think the author of the image didn’t consider the possibility of type annotation.

In fact if

- there are no type annotations and
- all the arguments are polymorphic and or function over polymorphic types,
- you don’t consider the existence of polymorphic operators such as = or <> 
  (otherwise it is wrong since <> and = have the same type and different implementation),

then there is only one pure implementation of your function signature.

(you can probably prove that by saying the only things you can use to define that function are :

- pure functions of the same type, that can be inlined, so you can ignore that
- match-patterns and let, for which the image’s argument is true
- cartesian product (let f a b = a, b)
- function composition
- infinite recursion
- and maybe other things I forget, but you can make an exhaustive list

and that the combination of these used can be guessed from the output and input types. 
)

Comment: This is incorrect. For example there is no implementation of a function of a type `'a -> 'b`.

Comment: "let rec f x = f x" is of type 'a -> 'b though

Comment: It's not a pure function, strictly. Non-termination can be considered a side effect.

Answer (score 2):

You are right. The attached image is incorrect even without type annotations.

At first, it's important to consider what kind of "equality" on implementations is assumed here. Let's consider the following examples.

1. Is `(@@)` equal to `(@@+)`?

   ```
   let ( @@ ) f x = f x
   let ( @@+ ) f x =
     let _ = 42 in
     f x
   ```
2. Is `(|>)` equal to `(|>+)`?

   ```
   let ( |> ) x f = f x
   let ( |>+ ) x f = f @@ x
   ```
3. Is `(%)` equal to `(%+)`?

   ```
   let ( % ) f g x = f (g x)
   let ( %+ ) p q r = p (q r)
   ```

If `(@@)` is not equal to `(@@+)`, then we can construct the 5th implementation of a function `bool -> bool`, such as `(fun x -> let _ = 42 in true)`.

Therefore, the author of the image would have wanted to distinguish functions not by its implementation (or codes), but by some other element such as its behavior (like [duck test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_test) or the equality on mathematical functions).

Still, the image is incorrect. The image claims "for pure functions that don't have any concrete type in the signature, there is only one possible implementation", but no. For example, there is no pure function `'a -> 'b`. This can be shown through [the Curry–Howard correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence).